# openssl check fails with Private key for terraform oci provider

Tags: openssl, terraform, azure-pipelines, private-key

I was getting an error while running `terraform plan` in azure pipeline agent (using terraform oci provider).

```
 Error: can not create client, bad configuration: did not find a proper configuration for private key
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/oci"],
│   on provider.tf line 4, in provider "oci":
│    4: provider "oci" {
```

This is the provider.tf:

```
## Provider file
## Define the provider

provider "oci" {
  tenancy_ocid     = var.tenancy_ocid
  user_ocid        = var.user_ocid
  fingerprint      = var.fingerprint
  private_key_path = var.private_key_path
  region           = var.region
}
```

All the variable values are passed using environment variables like `$TF_VAR_private_key_path`. The private key file is added to pipeline library secure files, and downloaded to the agent at the time of pipeline run through a task.

So checked if the file exists in the agent, and it is there.
Tried printing the .pem file with `cat` command. And the output seems fine.

And then I tried checking the .pem file with the openssl command, and it returns error:

```
$ openssl rsa -in $TF_VAR_private_key_path -check

unable to load Private Key
139790939505984:error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long:../crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:91:
139790939505984:error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:bad object header:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1137:
139790939505984:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=RSAPrivateKey
139790939505984:error:04093004:rsa routines:old_rsa_priv_decode:RSA lib:../crypto/rsa/rsa_ameth.c:133:
139790939505984:error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long:../crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:91:
139790939505984:error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:bad object header:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1137:
139790939505984:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
139790939505984:error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey:ASN1 lib:../crypto/pem/pem_pkey.c:88:
```

Can anyone please help to understand the actual problem with openssl?

**Note:**

There is no such error when the api_key file is provided directly in a directory through the repository files, instead of a secure file. May be secure file adds an extra encoding to the private key file ??

Comment: You may try to use `openssl asn1parse -in $TF_VAR_private_key_path` to check key contents or errors in the structure.

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky That returns error `140605148575040:error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long:../crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:91:
Error in encoding`

Comment: And, there is no such error when the api_key file is provided directly through the repository, instead of a secure file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error got fixed. I compared the contents of both the api files - one which was downloaded to the pipeline agent from secure files (`$TF_VAR_private_key_path`), and other one which was added as a file in the repository (`/home/vsts/work/1/s/terraform/api_keys/oci_api_key.pem`).

```
cat $TF_VAR_private_key_path
cat /home/vsts/work/1/s/terraform/api_keys/oci_api_key.pem
openssl rsa -in $TF_VAR_private_key_path -check
openssl rsa -in /home/vsts/work/1/s/terraform/api_keys/oci_api_key.pem -check
```

The problem was that **some lines were missing in the api key file that I added to secure files** of azure pipeline's Library. After uploading the correct api key file to secure files, everything worked fine!

[This](https://maximilian.tech/2020/11/04/tutorial-how-to-setup-terraform-for-oracle-cloud-infrastructure-oci-to-create-a-simple-web-server/) blog was stating some reasons for this error.

> If you get an error message such as `provider.oci: can not create client, bad configuration: did not find a proper configuration for private key`, you might have missed one of these things:
>
> - Not specifying either a private_key or private_key_path in the config
> - Specifying a private_key_path that’s not a valid path to a private key file
> - Not specifying a private_key_password for a private key that’s encrypted
> - Specifying an incorrect private_key_password for an encrypted private key
> - Set up your API key incorrectly